# mysql search min(date) within a range

Tags: mysql, min

I want to find the min date within a set range, example below I want to find the minimum application date for each student. MySQL does not accept this query.

```
SELECT MIN(applications.date) AS 'D', students.name
FROM applications, students
WHERE applications.student_id = students.id AND
D BETWEEN '2016-05-01' AND '2016-05-31'
GROUP BY students.id
```

Comment: in the WHERE you define wich ROWS are use. so it is not possible to use a result from the WHERE  "MIN(applications.date)" as condition in WHERE. use **AND applications .date BETWEEN '2016-05-01' AND '2016-05-31'**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, just use table column in `where` clause not a alias name;)

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT MIN(applications.date) AS 'D', students.name
    FROM applications, students
    WHERE applications.student_id = students.id
    GROUP BY students.id
) tmp
WHERE D BETWEEN '2016-05-01' AND '2016-05-31'
```

Comment: This will not work because it will search all date in that range and not minimum one only. This is exactly the problem I am having :(

Comment: Sorry, I mistook your question, I've updated my answer. Check it again please.

Comment: Thanks this works. :) But one disadvantage is it is much slower to calculate, so I may consider to use PHP to filter the date in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot apply filter using `where` clause on results from an aggregate function that is `min()` instead you can use `having` clause

```
SELECT MIN(a.date) AS `D`,s.id,s.name
FROM applications a
JOIN students s ON a.student_id = s.id 
GROUP BY s.id,s.name
HAVING `D` >= '2016-05-01' AND `D` <= '2016-05-31'
```